# Get only new data from new database and insert into old database

Tags: sql, database, magento

I have 2 exported database from magento 1

1- today's database (NEW)
2- Old database (OLD)

what I want is get all new data from new database to old database

for example, last order ID in old database is 131 and last order ID in new database is 161. I want to inset new order Id (from 132 to 161) in old database.

This will be applicable to all entity like (order,product,customer)

a general solution for all table will be appreciate
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I got solution:

First we need to select unique data from new table and insert it into old table by:

> INSERT INTO DB1.tb (select * from DB2.tb where sku not in(Select sku from DB1.tb));

**Where:**

DB1 - Old Database

DB2 - New database